# Quadram odd IBM PC card bracket

Tags: hardware, ibm-pc, rtc

I came across an early IBM PC ISA realtime clock/calendar card made by Quadram called the ["Chronograph" (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HfwE.jpg).  It's basically the same clock feature they incorporated into their QuadBoard lines, but in a standalone form.  What's odd is the metal card bracket is unusual and doesn't even fit into any PC case (no, not even a 5150).

[image]

MinusZeroDegrees has a photo of a [RAM board also made by Quadram](http://minuszerodegrees.net/quadram/quadram.htm) with the same bracket, and both are featured in [other promotional literature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC9Ll.jpg).

I've never come across any other cards like this and haven't been able to find any other examples online. There are no enlightening special instructions for installation in the manual - it simply says "The Clock/Calendar may be plugged into any available slot in the Personal Computer."  The only way apparently to use this card in a PC is to remove the bracket and put it in a slot just flopping around, maybe with a blank filler plate behind it.  I can't imagine that was the way it was intended to be used though.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: I've never seen any of those, but they *look* as if you could just screw them on top of an existing bracket, either the "blind" ones, or the secondary ones you had e.g. for the multi-port cards. There's even enough space for the connectors of those secondary brackets, so it'd be a clever way to use a slot behind a secondary bracket (which otherwise would be wasted).

Comment: Do you have a photo of it not fitting in the 5150 case?

Comment: TBH I haven't seen a bracket like that before, so I learned something new today. Thanks for posting the question!

Comment: Now try to screw it on top of a "secondary" bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It fits.

Okay, so I'd swear that I tried this when I got the card and it didn't fit.  But it took someone asking for a photo for me to try it again in a 5150 and....

[image]

Now it is a little bit awkward in a 5160 because it slightly blocks the adjacent card but it DOES in fact fit.

[image]

(facepalm)